# How to erase line from text file in Python?

Tags: python, io

I'm trying to make a code to rewrite a specific line from a .txt file.
I can get to write in the line i want, but i can't erase the previous text on the line.

Here is my code:
(i'm trying a couple of things)

```
def writeline(file,n_line, text):
    f=open(file,'r+')
    count=0
    for line in f:
        count=count+1
        if count==n_line :
            f.write(line.replace(str(line),text))
            #f.write('\r'+text)
```

You can use this code to make a test file for testing:

```
with open('writetest.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('1 \n2 \n3 \n4 \n5')

writeline('writetest.txt',4,'This is the fourth line')
```

Edit: For Some reason, if i use 'if count==5:' the code compiles ok (even if it doen't erase the previous text), but if i do 'if count==n_line: ', the file ends up with a lot of garbage.

The Answers work, but i would like to know what are the problems with my code, and why i can't read and write. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are reading from the file and also writing to it.  Don't do that.  Instead, you should write to a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) and then [`rename`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename) it over the original file after you finish writing and close it.

Or if the size of the file is guaranteed to be small, you can use `readlines()` to read all of it, then close the file, modify the line you want, and write it back out:

```
def editline(file,n_line,text):
    with open(file) as infile:
        lines = infile.readlines()
    lines[n_line] = text+' \n'
    with open(file, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use temporary file:

```
import os
import shutil


def writeline(filename, n_line, text):
    tmp_filename = filename + ".tmp"

    count = 0
    with open(tmp_filename, 'wt') as tmp:
        with open(filename, 'rt') as src:
            for line in src:
                count += 1
                if count == n_line:
                    line = line.replace(str(line), text + '\n')
                tmp.write(line)
    shutil.copy(tmp_filename, filename)
    os.remove(tmp_filename)


def create_test(fname):
    with open(fname,'w') as f:
        f.write('1 \n2 \n3 \n4 \n5')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_test('writetest.txt')
    writeline('writetest.txt', 4, 'This is the fourth line')
```